# How to delete row contain specific string on it in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, row

There are lots of rows that contain '08:28:00.000' in my table,like this one:

```
open    high    low close   volume  datetime
324.55  324.55  324.48  324.53  20945   2020-07-22 08:28:00.000
334.54  325.57  324.94  322.54  23947   2020-07-23 08:28:00.000
```

I want to delete all the rows that 'datetime' contains '08:28:00.000'.Instead of deleting this kind of rows one by one,is any command can delete all the rows than datetime contain '08:28:00.000'?

Comment: What is the logic here, and which parts of time do you want to use?  Hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds, all of the above?

Comment: I want to delete all the rows that 'datetime' contain '08:28:00.000'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a range delete query here, after extracting time from the `datetime` column:

```
DELETE
FROM yourTable
WHERE CONVERT(time, datetime) = '08:28:00.000';
```